# Android GPS accuracy indicator

Tags: android, gps

I'd like to have an indicator of GPS accuracy like Runkeeper it shows some bars. So when you have good GPS signals the indicator is full and when it is not, the bars are not full, kind of like your WIFI icon.

So let's say it has 3 bars .... 3 bars = Good, 2 bars = Average, 1 bar = Poor, 0 bar = no GPS.

Could I based on the location.getAcurracy() to draw those bars? If so, what acurracy would equal to 3 bars, etc ...

Thanks!

Comment: Set an maximum accuracy in meters like 20 and draw bars based on the percentage. :)

Comment: but how do i choose the number ? 20? 30? 40? ...

Comment: id suggest 20m = good, 50m = average, 100m = poor. working with GPS some time now and its not an accurate tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location.getAccuracy() describes the deviation in meters. So, the smaller the number, the better the accuracy.

If this location does not have an accuracy, then 0.0 is returned.

So you can keep it

0.0 as No Gps signal

1-25  - 4 bars

26-50 - 3 bars

51-75 - 2 bars

75-100 - 1 bar